# Worklight Push using UDID: Apple blocks UDID - Will it Work

Tags: push-notification, app-store, ibm-mobilefirst, udid

I have made an App based on Worklight Consumer Edition 5.0.5 and have done Push Notification.

As Apple has recently said to not accept new Apps that are using UDIDs.

I think Worklight is using UDIDs.

I want to now, Will Apple accept my App for App Store? or what i have to do now?

Do i have to upgrade App on 5.0.6 ? and it will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Worklight does not make use of UDIDs in general, and more specifically - UDIDs are not used for Push Notifications, rather a device token is.

In addition, version 5.0.6.1 contains further changes to make Worklight even more compatible with Apple's App Store guidelines; it is a recommended ugprade.

Comment: this is good, Thanks. Actually in the device logs i had seen UDID prefix and numbers that's why assumed Worklight is using it.